# transform.lookat issue (C# Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been going into a fix about how to get an object to rotate around like an orbit on another object.

```
if (Spin == true)  
{  
  transform.LookAt(ParentOrb.transform);  
  transform.Rotate(90,0,0);  
  transform.Translate(transform.forward*Time.deltaTime*5,Space.World);   
}
```

However, once the object that is supposed to orbit around the other object, when it hits the world y value of 0(Directly under/over) it starts to spin around like crazy.

I did change lookat's second argument to vector.3.up , transform.up and vector3.zero.

When I had vector3.up it was the same issue with the spinning.
When I had transform.up it started to spin around itself.
When I had vector3.zero it did instart spin around itself, but it was not relative to the actual orb, but it's own orbit.

I wish to be able to make it orbit itself around the parentorb in a full cycle.

Thanks for reading my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you may have just encountered [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)!

The glorious thing about Unity3D's framework is that there's usually an existing method for your solution. In this case there's [Transform.RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html).

This code should function closer to how you originally intended:

`transform.RotateAround(ParentOrb.transform.position, Vector3.back, 40f * Time.deltaTime);`

Where 40f is the arbitrary intended rotation speed (in degrees) per second.

Comment: Thank you so much  The Closest possible solution yet.^^

Comment: Ah, Been testing around, I was too hasty. ><  It seems that it doesn't rotate correctly around the object, since it was based on several income into the orbit area.  http://imageshack.us/a/img843/7434/rotations.jpg   
Something along these lines, where it starts to rotate around the specific orbit depending on location.
The one you gave me has only a stale orbit spin.
   
I guess I could try and use this function abit more to see if I can get it working.   

Most likely if I could make it rotate towards the center and then use .right.

Comment: Okay, I think I might be able to use this after all, Just make it so that when I press the button, I use Lookat the center, and then I need to find out how rotate the z according to the current direction.